# iOS / iPhone - Xcode debug area not showing object properties

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging, logging

After a recent upgrade of Xcode (6.1) I am no longer able to see the properties of objects in the debug area. Does anyone know how to return this functionality to Xcode?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Xcode has never shown properties per se in the Variables view.  If the property had a backing ivar, and there was debug information for the backing ivar, then that would be shown.  But to present the correct property view it would have to call the property accessor for every property of all the disclosed objects, and that's too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me before. Turn out, it was just because a tiny mistake.
So, I think you need to check two things:

1. Whether the break points you are setting are able to discover your properties. It's all about the scope problem.
2. To check whether you filter it out accidentally.

Comment: If I filtered it out, where would that be?

Comment: Bottom left corner of the debug area.

Comment: Oh I checked that but it's not the problem.. properties of objects are still not shown even if I choose 'All'

Comment: I'm ot sure what you mean by the scope of the breakpoint.. I'm setting breakpoints like I always have and am expecting to see the relevant objects and their properties.

Comment: Just want to make sure that it's not about setting that cause this error. As for the scope, perhaps the breakpoints you set are not able to discover that property? But I don't think you make that mistake.